# How to append Swagger config on a project whose config is in a 'core' project'?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, swagger, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

I don't know if this is possible, but it would make my life easier.
I have a big solution that consists of multiple parts. In the 'core' project there is a Swagger config and everything works fine. But in my app that uses that core part I have a need to customize and add some things to that Swagger config? Can that be done? I know that I can't register another Swagger config, but maybe there is a workaround? Like some override, or appending?

Comment: Add some code samples here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This cannot be done.
You need to edit the main Swagger config.